# typescript is searching for types of packages that aren't installed

Tags: typescript, firebase, npm, package.json

I've been working on a typescript project, specifically, I've been working in a firebase functions project, using typescript.

Whenever I run `firebase deploy --only functions` to deploy the functions I get these three cryptic errors:

```
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'linkify-it'.
  The file is in the program because:
    Entry point for implicit type library 'linkify-it'

error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'markdown-it'.
  The file is in the program because:
    Entry point for implicit type library 'markdown-it'

error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'mdurl'.
  The file is in the program because:
```

I get the same error if I run `npm run build` or `tsc` directly.

Here is the weird thing tho: Before today I had never in my life heard of the packages `linkify-it`,  `markdown-it` or `mdurl`, they are not, nor have ever been, dependencies in my project.
In fact, my project only has a handful of dependencies, most of which were added by firebase itself, here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts .",
    "build": "tsc",
    "build:watch": "tsc --watch",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.12.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint": "^8.9.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Here is my .tsconfig in case it's useful:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Interestingly, I managed to fix the problem by adding the types packages to my project

```
npm install @types/markdown-it @types/mdurl @types/linkify-it
```

But of course, that now means I have weird dependencies in my project, so I've been searching for a way to get rid of these dependencies.

I tried:

1. uninstalling `mdurl`,  `linkify-it` and `markdown-it`, to no avail, my project does not depend on them.
2. Deleting the node_modules folder and running `npm install` again, the problem is still there.
3. Removing other dependencies. I was able to remove pretty much every dev dependency, but the errors would not change, so I reinstalled them all.

I assume something I'm using depends on them, but it seems so weird that my project doesn't tell me why it needs these three packages, I also don't know what could my project possibly use these packages for, I mean the project has absolutely nothing to do with markdown.

I found a number of people with similar problems, namely [this gentleman](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27956), but all of the examples seemed to be solved by removing some weird dependency from their package.json, I can't find my weird dependency

Comment: Maybe set `skipLibCheck` to `false`? https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#skipLibCheck